# why z-index don't overlap these 2 squares?

Tags: html, css, z-index

hi guys i have this code

HTML:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="s1"></div>

            <div class="s2"></div>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
        .container{
        border:1px solid;
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
        }
        .s1{
        position:relative;
        z-index:1;
        background-color:red;
        height:30px;
        width:30px;
        }
        .s2{
        position:relative;
        z-index:2;
        background-color:green;
        height:90px;
        width:90px;
        }
```

I want the green square overlap the red square, but this not works.
Can someone explain me why? Thanks.

Comment: They're below each other, you need to position them on top of each other, Try `top:-30px;` on the green element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're all `position: relative`. Try setting to `position: absolute;`